# wicd doesn't connect to my iPhone USB personel hotspot

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, iphone, wicd

Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. wicd 1.7.2.3. iPhone 4s with iOS 6. When I connect the iPhone I see it as a camera. I can share the WiFi hotspot (of course possible even without connecting it).

`dmesg` shows:

```
[  594.800847] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using
ehci_hcd [  594.943719] ipheth 1-1.2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet
device attached
```

`ifconfig` shows eth1 (have got eth0, wlan0 and l0).

But how do I make wicd connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Wicd interface and press the arrow on the right.
Then hit "Preferences."
Under "Wired interface" put **eth1** and wicd will be able to connect.

Also you do not really need wicd for hardwired interfaces, just use **dhclient** to get an ip address:

```
$ sudo dhclient -v eth1
```